# addTarget:action:forControlEvents: from a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableViewCell with 3 checkmark buttons.  Each checkmark button is a custom UIButton (just the images really), and have an outlet in the custom UITableViewCell subclass.  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I

```
[cell.firstcheckmark addTarget:self action:@selector(checkmarkPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.secondcheckmark addTarget:self action:@selector(checkmarkPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.thirdcheckmark addTarget:self action:@selector(checkmarkPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)checkmarkPressed:(id)sender {
   // how do I get which checkmark was pressed?
}
```

I was not sure how to get which button was pressed from the sender object.  Other times I can use the title of the button, but in this case, all the buttons are the same except their outlet.  How do I get which button was pressed?  Or do they each need to call a different method, and then in each of those three methods, I can update my model by calling the same modelUpdateMethod: from each of those three methods?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify them by their tag:

```
cell.firstcheckmark.tag = 0;
```

And then

```
- (void)checkmarkPressed:(id)sender {

   UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

   if(button.tag == 0)
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can also use :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
```

it can get which cell the button in.